# Different documentation generated by rosdoc_lite online and offline

Tags: ros, documentation, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the [adhoc communication package](http://wiki.ros.org/adhoc_communication) or the [explorer package](http://wiki.ros.org/explorer) the documentation generated online and offline, especially the Package Summary, looks different. While online Author, Status, Link are missing, when generating the documentation offline the manifest.xml includes all information currently missing online. I've updated the repository last week but still the changes to not show online.

According to the [rosdoc_lite doc](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc_lite) the documentation should be generated if the package is listed in rosdistro - for hydro I assume rosdistro/hydro/distribution.yaml in which ad hoc is listed.

Related questions (see below) did not help unfortunately:

- [rosdoc and wiki updates](http://answers.ros.org/question/10214/rosdoc-and-wiki-updates/)
- [rosdoc generation for wiki](http://answers.ros.org/question/54243/rosdoc-generation-for-wiki/)

Can someone please elaborate what triggers rosdoc_lite and what data is used to generate the documentation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199317/different-documentation-generated-by-rosdoc_lite-online-and-offline/) by [torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/18186/torsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-12-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-12-12**:
You git repository is listed in a doc stanza within the Hydro distribution.yaml, so that looks right.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-12-12**:
The documentation status says: "No API documentation available". For some reason the build farm is not finding it. I don't know why.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-12-12**:
Could the residual manifest.xml be causing confusion?

**Comment by [torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/18186/torsten/) on 2014-12-12**:
I've deleted the manifest.xml just in case but didn't have the time to push this yet. But anyways, the documentation shows up correctly now. Can you tell how often the documentation is generated? The problem seems to have solved itself. How set the question answered if there is no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The build farm cycle probably varies, but it usually takes several days or a week to pick up new changes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0